# Magento 2.2.5 Show customer header links in Category navigation menu

Tags: magento-2.2.5, topmenu, header.panel

In Magento 2.2.5, Is there any way to display the top customer header links in Category navigation menu.

Like this

[image]

Comment: Customer header links are available 2 times in page, 1 is on top left side of page & second one is available in category navigation menu.
1st is used in desktop version & another is used in mobile/tab version.
So make 2nd one visible using css in both desktop&mobile version& hide 1st one.

Answer (score 0):

> Add below code in `Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` file

```
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
                <container name="header.bottom" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-bottom" after="-">
                </container>
    </referenceContainer>

 <move element="top.links" destination="header.bottom"/>
 <move element="navigation.sections" destination="header.bottom" after="top.links"/>
```

and run below command

```
php bin/magento cache:clean & php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: @Mohammed, Thanks for your suggestion. It is showing as one by one links. I need as it is with dropdown. Any possibilities.

Comment: Use below code to show links with dropdown,
<container name="header.links" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-links" after="-">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation" name="top.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>

        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <container name="header.bottom" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-bottom" after="-">
        </container>
</referenceContainer>

Comment: <move element="header.links" destination="header.bottom"/>
<move element="navigation.sections" destination="header.bottom" after="top.links"/>

Comment: I am geting this output. PLease check here. https://ibb.co/Xj1YLyW   I have a doubt. Why you moving these elements. "<move element="header.links" destination="header.bottom"/>
<move element="navigation.sections" destination="header.bottom" after="top.links"/>". Because of this, breadcrumbs are coming before the navigation links.

Comment: We are moving these elements to change the postion of Header links as you needed instead of default, if you are having issue with breadcrumbs then use below code to make the proper postion of breadcrumbs.

<move element="breadcrumbs" destination="main.content" before="-"/>

Comment: It is not rendering within the navigation section. Instead it is added as separate ul outside the div. Is it possible to move within the div(Exactly within the ul).

Comment: you have to manage that using the CSS. It is working fine for me,